# Добавление в друзья - отображает, но не как надо

Tags: php, mysql

Значит делаю добавление в друзья. Пользователь кликнул Добавить в друзья, запрос полетел в базу - с этим всё нормально, а тому пользователю которому предложили дружбу - на странице друзья отображаются заявки добавления. Но тут проблема. Например, у пользователя 3 заявки, и у всех них аватар и логин последнего давшего заявку. В таблице friends такие поля: id(auto_increment), ot, komu, status Вот такой код это реализует, подскажите, где ошибка:

```
$fr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE komu='$id' ORDER BY id DESC",$db); 
$fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr);
$aut = $fri['ot'];

$myr = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE login='$aut' ",$db);
$mi = mysql_fetch_array($myr);
do 
{
    printf("<iмg src='%s'>%s<br>",$mi['avatar'],$aut);
}
while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr));
```

Comment: @Кирилл Романтик Используйте форматирование кода: кнопка 101010 в редакторе.

Comment: эм...А с какого перепугу вы вдруг не принятый вопрос закрыли?))) причём неправильно закрыли :D

Comment: закрыл потому что я уже решил эту проблему. теперь другая возникла. пока сам стараюсь справиться. а как правильно закрывать?

Comment: Тему вообще закрывать могут только админы или уважаемые участники и в 70% если вам закрыли тему - к вам притензии...Если вы решили проблему то примите один из ответов...

Comment: ясен. буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка скорее всего в строчке `while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr));`, нужно скорее всего делать так `while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mi));`, Вот полный вариант вашего примера (исправленный и дополненный :-):

```
$fr = mysql_query(
    "SELECT ot FROM friends WHERE komu='$id' ORDER BY id DESC",
    $db
);
$fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr);
$aut = $fri['ot'];

$myr = mysql_query(
    "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE login='$aut'",
    $db
);
$mi = mysql_fetch_array($myr);
do {
    printf(
        "<iмg src='%s'>%s<br>",
        $mi['avatar'],
        $aut
    );
} while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mir));
```

Comment: попробовал, но выдаёт ошибку: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in www\friends.php on line 107 , а на 107 строке у меня: } while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mi));

Comment: У меня ошибка, там должно быть `while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mir));`

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но я уже всё сделал). теперь это выглядит так:
$fr = mysql_query("select * from friends, users where friends.komu='$id' and friends.ot=users.login order by friends.id desc",$db); 
$fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr);
do 
{
printf("<img src='%s'>%s<br>",$fri['avatar'],$fri['ot']);
}
while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($fr));

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте поставить `@` перед `mysql_fetch_assoc` или(`mysql_fetch_array`).
Для уверенности сделайте печать:

```
   ......................
    $myr = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE login='$aut' ",$db);

     $mi = @mysql_fetch_assoc($myr); 
    if(!$mi) echo "<h1>Error:".mysql_error()."</h1>";
```

Comment: выводится логин последней заявки и ошибка: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in friends.php on line 106, а на 106 строке: } while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mi));

Answer (score 0):

$myr может вернуть пустоту то есть если в таблице нет данных соответсвующие where она будет пустой и следовательно $mi['avatar'] такого ключа нет..нужно обращять внимание на запросы "SELECT ot FROM friends WHERE komu='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC" лучше писать так...
цикл без do организуйте...while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($mir) $mir используется только тут,где еще он используется? он должен возвращять ресурсный тип данных то есть ответ например на какой запрос к бд...